# Python - Looping through a multidimensional dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I explain what I think I am doing, I hope someone can explain where I am going wrong.

I have the following dictionary:

```
ls = [{
    'The Wolf Gift (13)': {
        'cover': 'V:\\Books\\Anne Rice\\The Wolf Gift (13)\\cover.jpg',
        'author': 'Anne Rice',
        'year': '1988'
    },
    'Mummy (14)': {
        'cover': 'V:\\Books\\Anne Rice\\Mummy (14)\\cover.jpg',
        'author': 'Anne Rice',
        'year': '1989'
    },
}]
```

First of all is the above a multidimensional dictionary? I want to make sure I am talking about the right thing. Secondly, how do I loop through it to retrieve the information at the various levels. The dictionary is dynamically populated so I do not know the keys before hand.

I have tried `for book in ls` and then `book['cover']` etc.. but it doesn't seem to work. I need the book name, and then the additional info for each book (cover etc...). I am pretty new to python. I come from PHP and using arrays are my bread and butter, but python is killing me....

Thanks

Comment: You have a one element list, which contains a dictionary, whose keys are the book name, and whose value is another dict...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a list containing a single dictionary. You can do something like:

```
>>> books = ls[0]
>>> for book, details in books.iteritems():
        print book,'-->', details['cover']
...     
Mummy (14) --> V:\Books\Anne Rice\Mummy (14)\cover.jpg
The Wolf Gift (13) --> V:\Books\Anne Rice\The Wolf Gift (13)\cover.jpg
```

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense to me. Out of interest, and because I am bound to come across it shortly. What if it was three levels deep. So `cover` also contained another dict `front:` and `back:` for example... How would I loop through then?

Comment: @superphonic Iterate over it inside the loop, do : `for cover,value in details['cover'].items():#do something.` If you're sure about the keys of `details['cover']`, then you can also access them directly: `details['cover']['front']`...

Answer (score 7):

Her is an example that could be used if `ls` contained more than one dictionary.

```
for dic in ls:
    for key in dic:
        print 'Book Name: %s' % (key)
        for value in dic[key]:
            print '\t%s: %s' % (value, dic[key][value])
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Book Name: Mummy (14)
    year: 1989
    cover: V:\Books\Anne Rice\Mummy (14)\cover.jpg
    author: Anne Rice
Book Name: The Wolf Gift (13)
    year: 1988
    cover: V:\Books\Anne Rice\The Wolf Gift (13)\cover.jpg
    author: Anne Rice
```

Or you could remove the final for loop and access the keys directly like so:

```
for dic in ls:
    for key in dic:
        print 'Book Name: %s' % (key)
        print 'Publish Year: %s' % dic[key]['year']
```

which will give the following output:

```
Book Name: Mummy (14)
Publish Year: 1989
Book Name: The Wolf Gift (13)
Publish Year: 1988
```

Answer (score 4):

ls is a list that contains a dictionary. This dictionary contains keys which are the books, and the values are dictionaries. So you can access them like this:

```
for book in ls[0]:
    covername = ls[0][book]['cover']
    print(covername)
```

which prints:

```
V:\Books\Anne Rice\The Wolf Gift (13)\cover.jpg
V:\Books\Anne Rice\Mummy (14)\cover.jpg
```

ls[0] refers to the first element in the list

[book] is because the keys of the dict are being iterated

['cover'] is the element being read from the dict refered to by [book]

Answer (score 3):

OK, so first of all your dictionary is actually a list containing a dictionary (you've got [] around its declaration). This might be a problem. Once you know this it's pretty easy to get all you want. For example:

```
for key in ls[0].keys():
     print ls[0][key]
```

Or, if you want to access particular detail about each book (contained in yet another dictionary within the outermost one holding each book):

```
for bookKey in ls[0].keys():
     print ls[0][bookKey]['cover']
     print ls[0][bookKey]['author']
     print ls[0][bookKey]['year']
```

Hope this helps. Maybe consider getting rid of this list around all this, will make your life a bit easier (one less index to use).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. You are right that the fact it's a list containing a dictionary was tripping me up in trying to access the elements...

Comment: I imagine :) Well good luck with your project and python. It's a pleasant language (although rather simplistic sometimes).