# Finding Values in a dict in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
dictProblems[tickets['IssueID']] = tickets['Subject'][len(TermProblem):], tickets['IssueDate'].strip()
```

meaning a single entry of `dictProblems` looks like this:

```
dictProblems[TicketId (int)] = (Subject (string), Date (date))
```

If I try to iterate all the values, I never get a hit:

```
if tickets['Subject'] in dictProblems.itervalues():
```

How do I iterate over multi-dimensional dict?

Comment: Can you add an example of one line in the dictionary please?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166581/python-looping-through-a-multidimensional-dictionary)

Comment: {5040: (u"please ignore, it's just a test!", u'2018-10-23T11:31:58.383Z'), 5042: (u"please ignore, it's just a test 2!", u'2018-10-23T11:53:14.473Z')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `dict.values` consists of an *iterable of tuples*. Testing for a `tuple` in such an iterable works directly, but *not* a scalar.

In Python 3.x, you can use `next` + `zip` to extract a `tuple` of the first values of each dictionary value:

```
d = {'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3, 4), 'c': (5, 6)}

3 in next(zip(*d.values()))                      # True
```

If you are going to perform such operations repeatedly, you can store these values in a `set` for O(1) access from then onwards:

```
values_set = set(next(zip(*d.values())))
3 in values_set                                  # True
```

Another option, viable with Python 2.7, is to use `any` with a generator comprehension:

```
any(3 == first for first, second in d.values())  # True
any(3 == i[0] for i in d.values())               # True
any(3 == next(iter(i)) for i in d.values())      # True
```

Comment: On your first idea: TypeError: list object is not an iterator

Comment: @Faulander, No, there's  no error with `d = {'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3, 4), 'c': (5, 6)}`. I can't help you transform / check your data because... you haven't provided any!

Comment: Staying with your example: {a:5042, ("please ignore, it's just a test!", "2018-10-23T11:31:58.383Z")}

Comment: @Faulander, Ah, you're using Python 2.7 perhaps? I've updated with advice on which versions work with which versions.

Comment: dictProblems[5042] = "please ignore, it's just a test!", "2018-10-23T11:31:58.383Z"
and yes, using python 2.7

Comment: @Faulander, So *use my data* and check the last 3 solutions. Then figure out why your data is different. You haven't supplied any data [**in your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52962298/edit), so it's tough for people to help further.

Comment: Thanks jpp, found the problem and accepted your solution. One question please: while comparing, how do i find the key in your first solution? (In the 2.7 one)

Comment: Best to use explicit indexing with `next` and a generator expression: `next((k for k, v in d.items() if 3 == v[0]), None)` gives `b`

Comment: jpp i don't understand your last post. can you explain a little more? i need to find out if tickets['Subject'] is in the dictionary and then give back the index, which is the ticket number.

Comment: @Faulander, This is a new question. I suggest you ask as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Really with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not searching for a specific date, you want to search only on the subjects:

```
if tickets['Subject'] in set(subject for subject, date in dictProblems.itervalues())
```

Comment: Does it really make sense to create a set here?

Comment: The idea was to keep the `in` operator to relate to the question, making it easier to understand where it went wrong

Comment: You can use `in` on any iterable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any()` with a generator expression to short-circuit the search once a match is found:

```
if any(tickets['Subject'] == subject for subject, _ in dictProblems.itervalues()):
```

Comment: doesn't find any values either :/